# How to allow Nginx in guest VM access shared folders in host os?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, webserver, ubuntu-12.10

## My setup

[image]

I want to setup a Ubuntu VM to act as a web server for development.

## Reason

I want to have a development environment as close to the actual production environment as possible.

## Problem

The above setup failed. I keep getting a File Not Found when I navigate to http://project1.localhost:8888

## What I tried

I did add `www-data` to the group `vboxsf` using

```
sudo adduser www-data vboxsf
```

before trying any of the below.

1. As mentioned, I tried the above setup. File not found error on webpage.
2. I tried the above setup but symlink from `/var/virtual/project1` to `/media/sf_WebApps/project1`. File not found error on webpage.
3. I tried to chown the `/media/sf_WebApps` from `root:vboxsf` to `www-data:vboxsf`. Not possible.
4. I tried to chmod the `/media/sf_WebApps` to 755. Not possible.
5. I made a copy of `/media/sf_WebApps/project1` and place the copy inside `/var/virtual`. This works, **but this is not what I want.** *Why not?* Because I want to easily use my host programs like github mac app and sublime text editor to make changes to the code base and see it reflected when I visit on browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is found [here from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/399971/61030).

Basically, you need to mount the (already mounted) shared folder as another user.

Type

```
mount -t vboxsf SHARE_NAME -o rw,dmode=777,gid=GROUP_ID,uid=USER_ID /path/on/guest
```

In this case, it will be

```
mount -t vboxsf WebApps -o rw,dmode=777,gid=GROUP_ID,uid=USER_ID /var/virtual/some_folder_name
```

If you want to do this mount every time you turn on the guest OS, create a file on /etc/init/SOMETHING.conf, with something like this:

```
description     "SOME DESCRIPTION"

start on starting

task
exec mount -t vboxsf WebApps -o rw,dmode=777,gid=GROUP_ID,uid=USER_ID /var/virtual/some_folder_name
```

To find out what is your uid or gid

```
 id -u username
 id -g username
```

Troubleshooting:

Always remember to first create the mount point first.

Always remember to install the GuestAdditions first. You can refer to http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html under Install Guest Additions.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
sudo apt-get install dkms -y

sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To edit /etc/group
2. To find the line contains "vboxsf"
3. To Add account after the colon (like www-data). If you need to add multiple accounts, you can separate them by commma
4. Relogin or reboot

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to the @KimStacks solution, but could not get `/etc/init/SOMETHING.conf` to work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, even if I changed [`start on starting`](https://superuser.com/questions/527963/how-to-allow-nginx-in-guest-vm-access-shared-folders-in-host-os/527991#527991) to `start on startup` like the [Stack Overflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889867/mount-shared-folder-vbox-as-another-user/10912770#10912770).

I found these steps much easier:

- Make a permanent mount point (use this location rather than `/media` once mounted):

  ```
  sudo mkdir /some/location
  ```
- [Get the uid and gid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889867/mount-shared-folder-vbox-as-another-user/10912770#10912770) of `www-data`:

  ```
  id www-data
  ```
- Edit the crontab file:

  ```
  sudo crontab -e
  ```
- Add a `@reboot` line [to make it run on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up/816#816) (replace `USER_ID` and `GROUP_ID` with the uid and gid from previous steps):

  ```
  @reboot mount -t vboxsf VirtualBoxFolderShareName /some/location -o uid=USER_ID,gid=GROUP_ID
  ```